# PHP- Count files on a server that connected with FTP

Tags: php, ftp

How to count number of files on a remote server that connected with FTP?

This is my code but it doesn't work

```
<?php
    @$ftp = ftp_connect("host");
    @ftp_login($ftp, "usr", "pwd");
    ftp_chdir($ftp,'uploads/');
    echo count(glob(ftp_pwd($ftp) . '*'));
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://php.net/ftp_nlist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use [`count()`](http://php.net/count) and [`ftp_nlist()`](http://php.net/ftp-nlist) functions combination:

```
$ftp = ftp_connect("host");
ftp_login($ftp, "usr", "pwd");
echo count(ftp_nlist($ftp, 'uploads/'));
ftp_close($ftp);
```

Answer (score 2):

use [ftp_rawlist](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rawlist.php) :

```
$files = ftp_rawlist($ftp, '/');

echo count($files).' files ..';
```

instead of

```
echo count(glob(ftp_pwd($ftp) . '*'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<?php
    @$ftp = ftp_connect("host");
    @ftp_login($ftp, "usr", "pwd");
    //ftp_chdir($ftp,'uploads/');
    //echo count(glob(ftp_pwd($ftp) . '*'));
    if ($handle = opendir(ftp_chdir($ftp,'uploads/'))) {
        while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false){
            if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..')) && !is_dir($dir.$file)) 
                $i++;
        }
    }
   echo "Total number of files:$i";
```